# How to increase a scope title and search bar's font size in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I've a search bar label with 3 scope titles in my app.
on iPhone the font size for these titles is nice but on iPad is too small and I don't find a R.R feature to change like an normal text in the storyboard!!
is there any easy way to solve this issue?

[image: see the image here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes:forState:` sets the text attributes for the search bar’ button’s title string for a given state.

```
 let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)   
 self.searchBar.setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : font], for: .normal)
```

Answer for your question in comments.

Update font size of `UITextField` in searchBar

Extract the `UITextField` object from searchBar by iterating over subViews, and then update font of it.

```
extension UISearchBar {
    func update(font : UIFont?) {
        for view in (self.subviews[0]).subviews {
            if let textField = view as? UITextField {
                textField.font = font
            }
        }
    }
}
```

update font use this method when initialize searchBar object

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar:UISearchBar!{
        didSet {
            searchBar.update(font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30))
        }
    }
```

Comment: it didn't change the size for me? shall I use in Viewdidload or something!

Comment: Yes, use this line of code in `viewDidLoad` method and make sure `searchBar` is connected from `@IBOutlet` or initiated programmatically.

Comment: nice it's working, one more thing please the "searchbar placeholder text" is small as well! Any solution?

Comment: @itch check updated answer for searchbar placeholder text.